# Adding bedroom in walkout basement

Tags: egress

Can 2 bedrooms share an egress window? Both bedrooms have separate entrances. They will share a door that leads to each room. Only 1 bedroom has egress window.

Comment: Are the 2 separate entrances directly to the exterior?

Answer (score 1):

The International Building Code and the International Residential Code both state that you only need a single clear egress path. However, if your maximum occupancy is more than 10 (in an R-1 structure), you are required to have two egress exits.

Two bedrooms with dedicated entry doors and a conjoining doorway should be sufficient. The additional window is a bonus in the one bedroom.

You can also call your local building inspector office for clarification.